# regex for typical username and password

Tags: java, regex

Using RegEx in java i'm attempting to generate a username and password:

alphabet, allows: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and @#$%!

username, at least one lowercase, at least one uppercase, alphabet, 5-13 ch

password, at least one lowercase, at least one uppercase, at least one number, alphabet, 5-13 ch

but every time that I run, my test username: aA0@! and test password: aA0@! keep showing my Toast message, which is indicating that the credentials are invalid.

```
Pattern uPattern = Pattern.compile("^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13})$");
Pattern pPattern = Pattern.compile("^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@#$%!])([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13})$");

if(!uPattern.matcher(mUserName.getText().toString()).matches()
 || !pPattern.matcher(mPassWord.getText().toString()).matches()){
 /* and if the patterns don't match, display a Toast message */
}
```

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13}` means the allowed string length is from 6 to 14. `aA0@!` is only 5 chars long.

Comment: +1, you're absolutely right. can i please have some more information on a good reference for regex beginners? thank you!

Comment: www.regular-expressions.info is a good one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please put your answer in the "Answer Question" area, so I can mark it. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13}` *consuming* part of your regex means the allowed string length is from 6 to 14. `aA0@!` is only 5 chars long.

There are two ways out depending on further conditions:

- If the chars allowed only include letters, digits and `@#$%!`, replace `([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13}` with `[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]{5,13}`
- If you want to allow any chars but line break chars, replace `([a-zA-Z0-9@#$%!]).{5,13}` with `.{5,13}` (that is, remove the capturing group).

See [Lookahead Example: Simple Password Validation](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password) for more hints how to streamline such regular expressions.